# Getting size of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I have initialized an NSMutableArray like so:

```
tileArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                 (tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tile8,tileBlank), nil];
```

I'm attempting to print out the size of the array by doing:

```
NSLog(@"Size2: %i", [tileArray count]);
```

It tells me that the size is 0.  What would be causing this?

The .h file

```
@interface STView : UIView{
NSMutableArray *tileArray;
TileView *tile1;
TileView *tile2;
TileView *tile3;
TileView *tile4;
TileView *tile5;
TileView *tile6;
TileView *tile7;
TileView *tile8;
TileView *tileBlank;

int width;
int height;
}

- (void) getScreenSize;
@end
```

TileView.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame   withImageNamed: (NSString*) imageName{
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
    //initilization code
    image = [[UIImageView alloc]
             initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    image.frame = self.bounds;
    image.opaque = YES;
    [self addSubview:image];
} return self;
}
```

Comment: Give more code, I'm interesting where you define the array and in which place you alloc it.

Answer (score 4):

First, remove the parentheses.  The value of the expression `(tile1,tile2,tile3,tile4,tile5,tile6,tile7,tile8,tileBlank)` is `tileBlank`.

Second, where are these `tile*` guys getting declared?  Are they all reliably non-null?

Comment: They should be non-null, but they are getting declared in the .h file.

Comment: How are they defined?  When do they get allocated and by what?

Comment: TileView is a class and is where, as far as I can tell, they are being allocated

Comment: Right but where's the line that says `tile1 = [[TileView alloc] initWithFrame:]` or similar?  A declaration does not create objects, only a definition can do that.

Comment: I see you've posted more code but you still don't show where `tile1` (or any of the others) are getting created.  You have to assign these in your STView somewhere, either by creating them and assigning them, or getting them from an IBOutlet, or some delegate or something.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to play around a bit more.  New to Objective-C, so it's taking a bit to get used to

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the array as a property in your .h and synthesize it then use self.titleArray.   Whatever function you declared the array in (e.g. viewDidLoad), it's only storing the info in that function.   In every other function it's nil, that's why you need the retained property.